# In Tkinter, i can't see the vertical scrollbar in an external file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

If i select `Tab2`, i would like to see the vertical scrollbar in the my `Verticalbar`, but i can't see the vertical scrollbar (in an external file `x.py`). I specify that the verticalbar is located outside the tabcontrol. Must stay out of tabcontrol. I don't get any errors

[image]
Let me explain: my `Verticalbar` is a white sidebar located on the right. I would like to use it as a **container** for all the tabs, but I would only like to modify the contents inside it. For example, when I select `Tab2`, I would like to display a frame (the **pink frame**) inside the `Verticalbar` and this happens correctly.

The problem is that I can't see the vertical scrollbar for the entire Verticalbar. What am I doing wrong? How to solve?

**EDIT CODE**

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Label, ttk
from page1 import Page1
from page2 import Page2
from x import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('705x325')

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('default')

#TABCONTROL
style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", padding= 7)
style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook', tabposition=tk.W + tk.N, tabplacement=tk.N + tk.EW,  background='black')
style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook.Tab', background='black', width=10, focuscolor='#efefef', foreground='#96de3d')
style.map('lefttab.TNotebook.Tab', background=[('selected', '#96de3d')], foreground=[('selected', 'white')])

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, style='lefttab.TNotebook')
intro = tk.Frame(notebook, bg='white', width=270, height=600)
tab1 = Page1(notebook, bg='white', width=270, height=600)
tab2 = Page2(notebook, bg='white', width=270, height=600)

notebook.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
notebook.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')

notebook.place(x=0, y=0)


#VERTICALBAR (RIGHT)
Verticalbar = Frame(root, width=200, height=400, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
Verticalbar.place(x=498, y=0)

def on_tab_selection_changed(event):
    # First, get the selected tab id
    tab_id = notebook.select()

    # Now we can get the tab text using the tab id
    tab_text = notebook.tab(tab_id, "text")
    if tab_text == "Tab 1":
        newlabel1 = Label(Verticalbar, text='TAB 1 EXAMPLE ', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
        newlabel1.place(x=2, y=3)

    if tab_text == "Tab 2":
        myfunction(Verticalbar)
        
# Bind to a virtual event to detect when the tab selection changes
notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", on_tab_selection_changed)

root.mainloop()
```

**x.py**

```
from tkinter import Frame, Label, Text, Tk, ttk
import tkinter as tk


def myfunction(Verticalbar):
    newlabel2 = Label(Verticalbar, text='TAB 2 EXAMPLE', background="pink", fg="black", font='Arial 10 bold')
    newlabel2.place(x=10, y=10)


    # scrollbar
    canvas = tk.Canvas(Verticalbar)
    scrollbar_frame = ttk.Scrollbar(Verticalbar, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas, width=200, height=400)

    scrollable_frame.bind(
        "<Configure>",
        lambda e: e.widget.master.configure(
            scrollregion=e.widget.master.bbox("all")
        )
    )
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_frame.set)

    #All_Page
    All_Page = Frame(scrollable_frame, width=200, height=400,
                                            background="pink", highlightbackground="#96de3d",
                                            highlightthickness=0) 
    All_Page.place(x=0, y=-12)

    textbox = Text(All_Page, height = 5, width = 10)
    textbox.place(x=10, y=10)


    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    scrollbar_frame.pack(side="right", fill="y")
```

**page2.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        #Don't put any code here, because more code will go here
```

**page1.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        #Don't put any code here, because more code will go here
```

Comment: it would be simpler if you would have all code in one file. We could simply copy code and run it - to see problem

Comment: @furas I know, but unfortunately this code is part of a larger project that i simplified and minified for the question in Stackoverflow. Could you help me? The files are reproducible.

Comment: I tried to run code but I see two problems. I have to resize window to see scrollbar on right side. When I switch tabs then it adds new elements but it doesn't remove old elements - so I see two pink canvas, two scrollbars, etc. Creating new widgets don't remove old widgets. Maybe you should create widgets only once and later replace settings in existing widgets (ie. replace text) when you switch tabs

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I see both tabs use the same `Verticalbar` which is `Frame(root)`. Maybe you should use two `Frames` and assign them to tow `tabs` not to `root`. Or to `page1`, `page2`

Comment: Now I see what you want to do but as I know standard `notebook` can't put element (your white frame) between notebook's pages (your right side) and notebook's switcher (TAB1, TAB2). You would have to create own widget for this. You may need to create column with `Buttons` `TAB1`, `TAB2` which will run code ti replace Frames on right side

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I removed old answer because there are new facts in question.

---

`Notebook` can't put item between `notebook's switches/tabs` and `notebook's pages`.

As I know `tkinter` can't change `parent/master` in `widgets` so you can't put `Frame` in on one page and later move it to other page.

(There is `grid(in_=parent)`, `pack(in_=parent)` but it has some restriction and I couldn't create working code)

It seems the only option is to skip `Notebook` and create `Frame` with `Buttons` (or even `Radiobuttons`) which will replace `page` in other `Frame` (using `.pack()` and `.forget()`)

---

Here is full working example:

[image]

I keep all code in one file - so everyone can simply copy and run it.

I was thinking about putting all in `class` to create widget but I skiped this idea.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- classes ---

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions 

def myfunction(page):

    # scrollbar
    canvas = tk.Canvas(page, width=100)
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    scrollbar_frame = ttk.Scrollbar(page, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar_frame.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    page.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: page.config(width=event.width))

    scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, width=227, height=1840, background='red')

    scrollable_frame.bind(
        "<Configure>",
        lambda e: e.widget.master.configure(
            scrollregion=e.widget.master.bbox("all")
        )
    )
    
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_frame.set)

    #All_Page
    all_page = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame, width=227, height=2840,
                                            background="pink", highlightbackground="#96de3d",
                                            highlightthickness=0) 
    all_page.place(x=0, y=-12)

    textbox = tk.Text(all_page, height=5, width=10)
    textbox.place(x=10, y=10)

    # place it after `canvas.pack()` - to see it on top of canvas (not behide canvas)
    new_label_2 = tk.Label(page, text='TAB 2 EXAMPLE', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
    new_label_2.place(x=2, y=3)
    

def switch_page(text):

    print('[switch_page] text:', text)

    text = radiobutton_var.get() 
    print('[switch_page] radiobutton_var.get():', text)
    
    if text == 'Tab1':
        page1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)  # show tab 1
        page2.forget()                        # hide tab 2
        
    if text == 'Tab2':
        page1.forget()                        # hide tab 1
        page2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)  # show tab 2
        
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('475x325')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')

# --- buttons ---

#root.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
#root.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

buttons_frame = tk.Frame(root)
buttons_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

radiobutton_var = tk.StringVar(root)  # keep information which button was pressed
#radiobutton_var.trace('w', lambda var, index, mode:switch_page((var, index, mode)))

b1 = tk.Radiobutton(buttons_frame, text='TAB1', variable=radiobutton_var, value='Tab1', indicator=0, command=lambda:switch_page("Tab1"))
b1.pack(ipadx=15, ipady=5)

b2 = tk.Radiobutton(buttons_frame, text='TAB2', variable=radiobutton_var, value='Tab2', indicator=0, command=lambda:switch_page("Tab2"))
b2.pack(ipadx=15, ipady=5)

# --- WhiteBoard ---

boards_frame = tk.Frame(root, background='white', width=200)
boards_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

l = tk.Label(boards_frame, text="WhiteBoard")
l.place(x=2, y=3)

# --- Pages ---

pages_frame = tk.Frame(root) #, background='#ffaaaa')  # color to see size and position of Frame
pages_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='news')

page1 = Page1(pages_frame)
page2 = Page2(pages_frame)

# ---

page1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)  # show first page
radiobutton_var.set('Tab1')           # select first button

# --- add elements to pages ---

new_label_1 = tk.Label(page1, text='TAB 1 EXAMPLE', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
new_label_1.place(x=2, y=3)

myfunction(page2)

# ---

root.mainloop()
```

---

New code after information in comments - it uses again `Notebook`

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random

# --- classes ---

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.page_label = tk.Label(self, text='PAGE 1', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
        self.page_label.place(x=2, y=3)

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.page_label = tk.Label(self, text='PAGE 2', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
        self.page_label.place(x=2, y=3)

class Page3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.page_label = tk.Label(self, text='PAGE 3', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
        self.page_label.place(x=2, y=3)

        # ---
        
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # use full height by row 0 ( 1/1 )
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # use half widht by col 0  ( 1/(1+1) )
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)   # use half widht by col 0  ( 1/(1+1) )  

        self.verticalbar = tk.Frame(self, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
        self.verticalbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

        # place it as the last - to show it at the top of other widgets
        self.label = tk.Label(self.verticalbar, text='VERTICALBAR 3', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
        self.label.place(x=2, y=3)

    def update_text(self):
        self.label['text'] = f'VERTICALBAR 3: Random {random.randint(0, 10)}'
   

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions 

def myfunction(page):
    #page.pack_propagate(0)
    
    canvas = tk.Canvas(page, background='#aaaaff', width=1)  # reduce width to page - to see scrollbar all time
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(page, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas, width=227, height=1840)
    scrollable_frame.bind(
        "<Configure>",
        lambda e: e.widget.master.configure(
            scrollregion=e.widget.master.bbox("all")
        )
    )

    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    # all_Page
    all_page = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame, width=227, height=2840,
                                            background="pink", 
                                            #highlightbackground="#96de3d",
                                            #highlightthickness=0,  
                                            )
    all_page.place(x=0, y=0)

    textbox = tk.Text(all_page, height=5, width=10)
    textbox.place(x=10, y=0+10, anchor='nw')      # `nw` - position of top left corner (North West)

    textbox = tk.Text(all_page, height=5, width=10, background='#aaffff')
    textbox.place(x=10, y=1840-10, anchor='sw')   # `sw` - position of bottom left corner (South West)

    # place it as the last - to show it at the top of other widgets
    new_label_2 = tk.Label(page, text='VERTICALBAR 2', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
    new_label_2.place(x=2, y=3)
    
def on_tab_selection_changed(event):
    # First, get the selected tab id
    tab_id = nb.select()

    # Now we can get the tab text using the tab id
    tab_text = nb.tab(tab_id, "text")
     
    if tab_text == 'Tab1':
        new_label_1['text'] = f'VERTICALBAR 1: Random {random.randint(0, 10)}'
        
    if tab_text == 'Tab2':
        pass

    if tab_text == 'Tab3':
        page3.update_text()
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('475x325')

style = ttk.Style(root)
#style.theme_use('default')
style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook', tabposition='wn')

# ---

nb = ttk.Notebook(root, style='lefttab.TNotebook')
nb.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
# Bind to a virtual event to detect when the tab selection changes
nb.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", on_tab_selection_changed)

# --- 
page1 = Page1(nb, background="#aaffaa")
page2 = Page2(nb, background="#aaffaa")
page3 = Page3(nb, background="#aaffaa")
nb.add(page1, text='Tab1', compound='left')
nb.add(page2, text='Tab2', compound='left')
nb.add(page3, text='Tab3', compound='left')

# --- page 1 ---

page1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # use full height by row 0 ( 1/1 )
page1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # use half widht by col 0  ( 1/(1+1) )
page1.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)   # use half widht by col 0  ( 1/(1+1) )  

verticalbar1 = tk.Frame(page1, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
#verticalbar1.pack_propagate(0)   # don't resize or shrink to children size
verticalbar1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

# place it as the last - to show it at the top of other widgets
new_label_1 = tk.Label(verticalbar1, text='VERTICALBAR 1', background="white", fg="#78b130", font='Arial 10 bold')
new_label_1.place(x=2, y=3)

# --- page 2 ---

page2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # use full height by row 0 ( 1/1 )
page2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # use half widht by col 0  ( 1/(1+1) )
page2.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)   # use half widht by col 0  ( 1/(1+1) )  

verticalbar2 = tk.Frame(page2, background="white", highlightthickness=0)
#verticalbar2.pack_propagate(0)   # don't resize or shrink to children size
verticalbar2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

myfunction(verticalbar2)

# --- 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am aware of the first problem. I know. I simply decided not to raise it now, but in the future.

I know Tab2 is supposed to use page2, but in page2 I already have very long code that isn't about this. So I was thinking of creating the x.py file to insert the Verticalbar code. In your code (which is fair and square), you are using myfunction(page2), but that's not what I wanted. I would NOT use page1 and page2 for these purposes, but only x. Could you please change the basic idea of your code? Your idea was correct, but that's not what I was looking for

Comment: IGNORE Page1 and Page2. I would like to continue to keep the project structure like mine, because it is part of a project already started. There is a lot of code written in the files, so I wanted to use x.py. IGNORE Page1 and Page2, don't use them. While in x.py I would like to create the scrollbar. For the rest, you can modify the code as you want.

Comment: if you want to  keep elements on `tabs` then you HAVE TO use `page1` and `page2`. Other solution will need even more changes.

Comment: I noticed an error on my part in the code, an oversight. The verticalbar, on the window, is OUTSIDE Tab1 or Tab2

Comment: I added my full working code. I deleted `verticalbar` from my code - because it was useless. If you use `root` as parent for `Frame` - `Frame(root)` - then `tkinter` will not keep it in tab because it is not part of `page`. `Frame` would need `page2` as parent.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't looking for this. You were kind, but I wrote the question wrong. Verticalbar goes outside the Tabcontrol: on the same screen, but outside. I'll try to update the code now, but if I can't I'll update it tonight. Sorry if I didn't understand the problem. I hope you will still help me even after the update. Thank you

Comment: if you write new question on new page then you can write `@furas` in comments and SO will inform me about question.

Comment: I don't know if Stackoverflow will make me write a new question. Maybe he'll delete it for me because it's similar to this one
​

Comment: so you may try to edit current question and better describe problem. You can add text `EDIT:` to show that you make changes. I can also edit my answer to create better answer when you show new details.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it and tag you in the comments. Thanks for the kindness. I appreciate it so much. And sorry if I got confused writing part of the code, but writing at night, when tired, it can happen. Thank you. We'll talk to you in a few hours.

Comment: I fixed the code and now it's what I asked for. The verticalbar is outside the Tabcontrol. As you can see, I also added an image of what I would like to achieve. You said that when I fixed my code, then I had to tag you. (Could you show me a version where there are external files and not everything in one file?) Thanks

Comment: Now I see what you want to do but as I know standard `notebook` can't put element (your white frame) between notebook's pages (on your right side) and notebook's switcher (TAB1, TAB2, on your left side). You would have to create own widget for this. You may need to create column with `Buttons` `TAB1`, `TAB2` which will run code to replace Frames on right side

Comment: Create a column with TAB1, TAB2 buttons? Are you sure there aren't other better ways? :(

Comment: `notebook` create `tabs` like any other programs - they have switchers directly next to  pages. Eventually you would have to create two `verticalbar` and put them in two `pages` and duplicate content when you switch tab. Or you can try to put `verticalbar` on top of other widget (using `root` and `place()`) but you will have to control content in pages to keep elements visible (not hidden behide `verticalbar`)

Comment: Mmm! You wrote "Eventually you would have to create two verticalbars and put them in two pages and duplicate content when you switch tab". But I don't want to create the verticalbar in pages. The verticalbar must be outside the pages. I don't get your other idea. However, could you change your answer please? If you need help, I will be happy to accept and vote for you. Thank you

Comment: you can't have `verticalbar` outside pages between `notebook's pages` and `notebook's switches`. Normally `notebook` wasn't created to put elements between `notebook's pages` and `notebook's switches`. You would have to create own `notebook` from scratch - and this may need to create separated `Frame` with `Buttons` as I suggested in previous comment.

Comment: I replaced answer with new code which use buttons to switch pages.

Comment: I wanted to keep the entire Tabcontrol (Notebook) structure, but if you say that it's not possible with the Notebook, then ok, i understand.

I only have one problem for your solution: as you have seen from my code, i try that the contents of the WhiteBoard must also change when I select TAB1 or TAB2. In your solution, only the verticalbar changes. When I click on TAB2, is it possible to modify both the contents of the Verticalbar (as you have already done) and the WhiteBoard? So simultaneously change two things at the same time: WhiteBoard and Verticalbar. It's possible to do it?

Comment: now I don't understand your problem - I use `WhiteBoard` in place of your `Verticalbar` - because I thought you want the same `Verticalbar` for both tabs. But if you want to change content in `WhiteBoard` then maybe you should create two different `WhiteBoard` and put them directly in tabs. And then you can use normal `Notebook`

Comment: frankly I don't understand all problem because your image and code looks like you have three parts: buttons (on left), white rectangle (in the middle), pink rectangle (on right). And I thought you want to display exactly the same content in white rectangle (in the middle) for all tabs. But now I see you want to change content in white rectangle (in the middle) - so I would create two rectangles - one in tab1, and one in tab2

Comment: I understand. But no, the contents of the white rectangle (in the center) are different for each tab.I didn't specify it in the question, because using Notebook I took it for granted that I could modify the contents inside it. Yes, I would need a rectangle in Tab1 and a rectangle in Tab2. For example if I select TAB1, I would like to get a white rectangle with X_1 inside and also a pink rectangle with X_2 inside.While if I select TAB2 I get a white rectangle with Y_1 inside and also a pink rectangle with Y_2 inside. Now that that's clarified,can I use Notebook or can't I use it anyway?

Comment: with this explanation I see you have to use two `white rectangles`. One in `tab1` and one in `tab2` - and I don't understand why you tried to use one `Verticalbar = tk.Frame(...)` for both tabs (in `page1` and `page2`). And if you will use two `white rectangles` then you can use `Notebook`.

Comment: Could you modify your solution code and show me how I can achieve this? I've always used Notebooks and I couldn't do it myself using your code, because I've never used this type of logic in tkinter. You're teaching me something new. Trusting in your kind help, I will be happy to vote and accept your solution after modification. Thank you

Comment: I think you had code in my old answer :) DId you keep code from my old answer? I would have to search in folder to check if I keep it.But it would need to get your original code and create two: `Verticalbar1` and `Verticalbar2` with different parents `page1` and  `page2`

Comment: I only have the code of your current solution. I'm confused for a moment about what I should do :'( Could you show me what code I should use as a complete solution please? Thank you

Comment: I put new code at the end of answer. I add some changes and comments but I stop working with this. BTW: I keep some examples from my answers on GitHub: [furas / python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples) but without descriptions.

Comment: Why did you use Notebook again? This is great news for me, because my project included a lot of code and used Notebook. From what you said before, I believed that to get what I wanted...I couldn't use Notebook. What made you change your mind?

Comment: but I wrote in previous comments that if you display different content in every `tab` (in every `Verticalbar`) then you need two `Verticalbar` - one in `tab1`, and one in `tab2` - and then you can use `Notebook` because you don't have to put shared `Verticalbar` between `notebook's switches` and `notebook's pages`.

Comment: I think we have to end this discussion because we don't understand each other :)

Comment: Ok understood. Thank you. I'll check your code better tonight. Now I go to sleep. See you tonight, see you soon

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Thank you